# Java JPA OrderBy Field and multiple column condition search not working

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, openjpa

I am try to fetch the data from mysql table with some condition and ordering using JPA. My code is working perfect without order, if i included the order i am getting zero records(its not a expected).

i get the generated query from console and run in mysql cmd. i am getting the result but not working through JPA

Please help me

```
    USER TABLE
    --------------------------------------------------
    NAME    | AGE  | ROLE      | ROLE_CD | CITY_CODE
    -------------------------------------------------
    name1   |  24  | developer | SR_DEV  | ch1      |
    name2   |  25  | tester    | SR_QAE  | ch2      |
    name3   |  26  | developer | DEV     | ch1      |
    name4   |  27  | tester    | QAE     | ch4      |


    ADDRESS TABLE
    --------------------------------
     STATE    | CITY    | CITY_CODE
    --------------------------------
    state1    | city1    | ch1      |
    state2    | city2    | ch2      |
    state3    | city3    | ch3      |
    state4    | city4    | ch4      |




    public class User {

        @Column(name =  "NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name =  "AGE")
        private String age;

        @Column(name =  "ROLE")
        private String role;

        @Column(name =  "ROLE_CD")
        private String roleCd;

        @Column(name =  "CITY_CODE")
        private String cityCode;

        @OneToOne   
        @JoinColumn(name = "cityCode", referencedColumnName = "cityCode",
            insertable = false, updatable = false, 
        foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)) 
        private Address address;
    }

    public class Address {
        @Column(name =  "CITY_CODE")
        private String cityCode;
        @Column(name =  "CITY")
        private String city;
        @Column(name =  "STATE")
        private String state;
    }


    public class OrderByField implements Order {

        private Expression<?> expression;

        @Override
        public Order reverse() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAscending() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Expression<?> getExpression() {
            return expression;
        }

        public OrderByField(CriteriaBuilder cb, List<Expression<?>> list) {
            this.expression = cb.function("FIELD", String.class, list.toArray(new Expression<?>[list.size()]));
        }
    }



    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> userData = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);

    Join<User, Address> joinAddress = userData.join("address");

    //Order By field ROLE_CODE
    List<Expression<?>> roleList = new ArrayList<>();
    roleList.add(userData.get("roleCd"));
    roleList.add(builder.parameter(String.class, "param1"));
    roleList.add(builder.parameter(String.class, "param2"));

    OrderByField order = new OrderByField(builder, roleList);//created custom class for ordeBy field

    //WHERE CLUASE city like city1 and role like developer
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    predicates.add(builder.like(joinAddress.get("city"), "%" + "city1" + "%"));
    predicates.add(builder.like(userData.get("role"), "%" + "developer" + "%"));

    criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    criteriaQuery.orderBy(order);

    TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    //ORDER BY FIELD PARAMS
    query.setParameter("param1", "SR_DEV");
    query.setParameter("param2", "DEV");

    //THIS FOR LIMIT THE RECORD
    if (pageNumber != null && pageSize != null) {
        query.setFirstResult(pageNumber * pageSize);
        query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    }

    return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: The first thing I see is that you have declared a `OneToOne` relationship involving `User.address`, but that is inconsistent with the data presented.  Did you mean for there to be dupes in the `USER.CITY_CODE` column?

Comment: sorry John Bollinger, I am not get your question. USER.CITY_CODE is for forign key

Comment: my issue is in Order. if i remove the order i am getting the expected result

Comment: name1   |  24  | developer | SR_DEV  | ch1      |

Comment: name1   |  26  | developer | DEV         | ch1      |

Comment: You have two different rows in your `USER` table that have the same value in the `CITY_CODE` column (`ch1`).  You've told JPA that this column serves as a foreign key for a *one-to-one* relationship, but that implies that no two users have the same address, a condition that is not satisfied by the actual data.  It is unclear to me whether it is the data that are wrong or the JPA annotation.

Comment: sorry john its my mistake. i edited the user table. user name1, name3 has same address code

Comment: I'm not talking about duplicate *names*.  Those are not an issue for the relationship multiplicity I'm talking about.  If multiple users are permitted to have the same address then the relationship declared on `User.address` must be `@ManyToOne`, not `@OneToOne`.  I'm not confident that fixing that will resolve the problem you asked about, but it might, and at minimum it will rule out that possibility.

Comment: no john, ManyToOne is not working. i tried

Comment: Whether it solves the problem or not, it is a necessary correction.

Comment: ok john, i correct the relation. any other idea

Comment: Not at the moment.